# Tools for testing look angle generator?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit

I'm looking for a software test tool with a specific capability:

Given the lat/long/altitude of a point on the ground and the az/el/range from that spot to a point in space, generate a TLE for a simulated satellite that will fly through that point at a specific time.

So, kind of a satellite tracker in reverse. Has anyone come across such a thing?

Comment: The problem is *way underspecified*. You can have a wide range of semimajor axes, eccentricities and inclinations that will all pass through a given look-angle cone for example. That said, it's an interesting question!

Comment: I agree, there are an infinite number of orbits which could fulfil that requirement, so you'd need to add some additional constraints. Forcing it to be a circular orbit with the lowest inclination possible would limit it to two possible orbits if I've visualised it correctly.